# How to copy files from a ** desination to another in Gulp src and dist?

Tags: gulp, src, radix

I have some problem can't find a direct answer on just this one. 
I have a folder structure like this:

```
modules/**/views/**/*.html
```

- modules/cart/views/templates/
- modules/cart/views/content/
- modules/cart/views/content/foo/

I want to move them so they end up like this:

- Views/templates/
- Views/content/
- Views/content/foo/

I have tried base: and cwd: with

```
{ base: 'modules/**/views/**' }
```

Also with . and ./ etc.. but cant get it to work with two ** I dont want the first ** just files from the second ** and it's folder

Any clue? does it even work? Tried

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using gulp-rename.
Not sure if it's the best one but worked. 
I split my path. Get the name of the first **
renamed it to empty value, same with the views.

```
return gulp.src(config.vSrc)
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            var splitedPath = path.dirname.split('\\');
            var moduleName = splitedPath[0];
            path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(moduleName, '').replace('views', '');
            gutil.log(path.dirname);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("Views"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To update this answer, now a good way to do this is with [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten).  It is very good at extracting specific folders from the folder hierarchy.  I believe in the OP's case what he wants is:

```
gulp.src(['config.vSrc'])
  .pipe(flatten({ subPath: [3] }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('Views'));
```

That should get the 4th, etc. folder on down.  It is possible you would need this syntax:

subPath: [3,]  I am not sure about that without testing it.